# How to test ether value in truffle test script using Mocha and chai

Tags: ether, truffle-test, mocha

I'm having a method inside my contract which return a variable having value is 100 ether for example. E.g:

```
uint256 private baseline

constructor() {
    baseline = 100 ether;
}

function getBaseline() external view returns (uint256) {
    return (baseline);
}
```

I've tried to write a test function:

```
const Contract = artifacts.require("MyContract");

contract("MyContract", (accounts) => {
  it("test", async () => {
    const instance = await QuickPunk.deployed();
    const baseline = await instance.getBaseline();

    console.log(baseline);
    expect(baseline).to.equal(100);
  });
});
```

But it doesn't work, and here are the logs:

```
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 25821184, 13721111, 22, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 3,
  red: null
}
```

and having this error: `AssertionError: expected <BN: 16345785d8a0000> to equal 100`

I wonder is there anyway I can assert baseline value with Truffle & Mocha?
Have tried to search around but seems like there is not much document about this on truffle website.

Comment: The problem is that javascript's numbers don't support the precision required by Ethereum so web3 uses a library bn.js. Now chai doen't known anything about bn.js objects. You could use a library like [chai-bn](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-bn/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used web3 API inside of the test file to convert the value into the value that I was expected.

web3 API already embedded globally inside of truffle test file. I just need to utilize `web3.utils.toWei` to convert 100 ether into Wei, and then convert Wei into BN by using `web3.utils.toBN`, then perform the assertion.

```
it("test", async () => {
    const instance = await QuickPunk.deployed();
    const baseline = await instance.getBaseline();

    const expectedBaseline = web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toWei("100", "ether));

    expect(baseline).to.deep.equal(expectedBaseline);
});
```